# Is it possible to download an apk from an email onto an Android 2.2 phone, and then run it

Tags: apk

The micro usb on my phone broke and I need to continue development of an application while I wait for the replacement. Can I send my program's apk package to myself then download it onto the phone and run it. If so, how might I accomplish this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you not have an SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

The GMail app won't allow downloading of attachments (images and the like are only "previewed") but you could use a third-party email app or the GMail the website to get around that.  Be aware that unless you have something like [Download Crutch](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/org.ouroborus.android.downloadcrutch/) installed, Android may not let you download APKs through the default browser.  You can just use Firefox or another browser instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Wi-fi you can use a remote file transfer tool like [WebSharingLite](https://market.android.com/details?id=nextapp.websharing&feature=search_result).

You can start the app, browse it in any web browser with the IP and port and upload your .apk or explore your files.

Answer (score 0):

To install .apks from sources other than the android market, you have to enable the "Unknown Sources" feature in the "Settings/Applications" menu. Otherwise, you will not be able to use any third party apps. For example, nothing from the Amazon app store can be installed without this setting.

Also, Dolphin Mini browser is great, lightweight, and allows direct installation of downloaded .apks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your cord is broken and you're looking for a way to transfer files effectively (including .apks), try [WiFi File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-file-explorer-pro/com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorerPRO). There's a free version, but the paid one lets you push files to your phone, and i found it to be perfect for transferring .apks without a cord.